# dom generated images sec by angular giving GET error because of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angularjs and jquery.

I have a list of article generated with images inside like this :

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in things">
           <img src="thing.src" /> blablabal
        </li>
```

I have this error which really annoy me even if doesn't influence the user view :

```
GET http://localhost:3000/img/%7B%7B%thing.src%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

What could I do ?

Comment: Put another quotation mark on the end of thing.src

Comment: change your declaration to `ng-src="thing.src"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like there:

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in things">
   <img ng-src="{{thing.src}}"/> blablabal
</li>
```